# Android: Conflict between Android SDK and Facebook for Android app

Tags: android, facebook

I have an app that uses the Facebook Android SDK. All works well (Facebook login, Like functionality) until I installed the Facebook for Android 3rd party application.

Without the 3rd party app, I get the WebView when choosing to login to Facebook. But with the Facebook app installed, user gets directed to the FB app for login (I believe it launches the activity for that app).

Is there a way to prevent my app from using the 3rd party app for anything Facebook related that I do on my app, and only use the WebView from the SDK for login?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9240416/android-faceboook-sso-login-failed-invalid-keyandroid-key-mismatch

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alrighty, read through the source code of Facebook SDK and reviewed the `authorize` method, and found my answer.

Found out that it's not a conflict but that's just how the way it works. The Facebook SDK prefers Single Sign-On, where available which means it will definitely use the Facebook for Android app for Login.

In the purposes of answering the question (how to prevent app from using 3rd party app), this is what I did:

```
mFacebook.authorize(context,
                new String[] { "user_photos", "friends_photos", "publish_stream" },
                -1, 
                (DialogListener) dialogListener);
```

I just added the 3rd parameter which is the activityCode. Facebook SDK checks whether the value is greater than or equal to zero, and use Single Sign-on.

And now I know that the ideal and preferred way is to use the Facebook SSO method.