# Facebook integration working in emulator but not working in android device?

Tags: android, facebook

I have integrated Facebook API in my Android application with Facebook login and post comments are working in emulator but same things are not working on actual device. I have created Android hash key properly from command prompt and configure this key into my Facebook developer Native android app block, but it is giving me this error on device

> Invalid android_key parameter. The key AmDG_kt_yelljlsj.. does not
>   match any allowed key.Configure your app key hashes at
>   http:/facebook/developer.

Thanks.

Comment: check out [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9240576/2345913)

Answer (score 1):

Turn off the sand box mode and activate the live mode of your application that you created on developer site.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have created hashKey for emulator not for device, there must be 2 hashkey, if you want to test the app on emulator. So please take a look in it, may be it is creating issue.

Or check Sandbox mode is on or off.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution for invalid android key parameter.

Generate KeyHash and configure into facebook native console account where we create facebook app id.

```
try {
                  PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.sipl.virtualbinoculars", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
                  for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                        md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                        Log.d("KeyHash:",Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
                        System.out.println("KEY HASH: "+Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
                  }
                } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                    Log.d("KeyHash:",e.getMessage());
                } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                    Log.d("KeyHash:",e.getMessage());
                }
```